# Ho can I find the sum of this sequence?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

There is a sequence
$$
 F_n= 
\begin{cases}
    aF_{n-1}+q^{n-2}F_{n-2},& n \text{ is even}\\
    bF_{n-1}+q^{n-2}F_{n-2},& n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
with the initial conditions $F_0 = 0 $, $F_1 = 1$.Here $q$ is just a smybol. The first terms of this sequence are $\{0,1,a,ab+q,\ldots\}$. The following function satisfies $F_n$ as
$$
F[n] = a^{1-\xi(n)}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \rfloor} {n-k-1\brack k}(ab)^{\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor -k}q^{k^2},
$$
where ${n\brack k}$ $=$ ${\frac{[n]_q !}{[k]_q ! [n-k]_q !}}$, $[n]_q != [1]_q[2]_q[3]_q \ldots[n-1]_q [n]_q$ and $[n]_q = 1+q+q^2+\ldots q^{n-1}$. Also 
$
 \xi(n)= 
\begin{cases}
    0,& n \text{ is even}\\
    1,& n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
$ is a parity function and $\lfloor ,\rfloor$ is floor function. Now, I have a different sequence as

$$
 C_n= 
\begin{cases}
    bC_{n-1}+q^{n-2}C_{n-2},& n \text{ is even}\\
    aC_{n-1}+q^{n-2}C_{n-2},& n \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$
with the initial conditions $C_0=2$ and $C_1=a$. The first terms of this sequence are $\{2,a,ab+2,a^2 b+a q+2a,\ldots\}$. I try the following functions, to obtain the same results with the new sequence, which are

$$
C[n] = a^{\xi(n)}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} \frac{[n]_q}{[n-k]_q}{n-k\brack k}(ab)^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor -k}q^{k^2},
$$

and 
$$
C[n] = a^{\xi(n)}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} \frac{[n]_q}{[n-k]_q}{n-k\brack k}(ab)^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor -k}q^{\binom{k}{2}}.
$$

Unfortunately both $C[n]$ doesn't give the same results with $C_n$. How can I modify $C[n]$ to obtain elements of $C_n$?